# Google Sheets: some percentages w/o decimal places contain a dot "." between number and percentage sign - others do not

Tags: google-sheets

I wasn't even sure how to describe this anomaly in Google Sheets. When writing full percentages without decimal places from 0% to 200% in 1% increments, certain percentage values have a "." added between the number and the %-sign - but only in the formula field, not in the cell itself (see screenshot). This makes working with the numbers, especially in text super annoying as then the "." is carried along (e.g., compare B13 with B15)

Is this a known bug or by others reproducible? Or am I missing something?

[image: percentage formatting bug]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug. Google is aware of the issue, but they consider it "cosmetic" so it is uncertain when it will be fixed or whether it will be fixed at all.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the hint. At least =SUBSTITUTE(B15,".","") works, but might of course create additional problems in statements or texts where other dots are wanted.